# Obj-c - Number table cells descending instead of ascending?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a UILabel in my cells that displays the count (1, 2, 3, 4...) beginning with 1 at the top. However, how can I make the count descending instead? Seems simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

My current code:

```
 cell.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)indexPath.row +1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just subtract the total number of items from indexpath.row

```
cell.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)(items.count - indexPath.row)];
```